# Proof of nonhomogeneous Poisson Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Consider a Poisson process with intensity function $\{\lambda(t),t\ge 0\}$. How should I prove that the number of arrivals in interval $[t,t+s]$ follows a Poisson distribution as follows:
$$
P\{ N(t+s)-N(t)=n\}=e^{-[m(t+s)-m(t)]} \frac{\big[m(t+s)-m(t) \big]^n}{n!}, \quad n=0,1,...
$$
where
$$
m(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\lambda(u)du.
$$

I wanna prove it by induction, but I failed to do it.

Comment: What's your definition of a Poisson process with nonhomogeneous intensity?

Comment: Arrival rate is a function of time and has the following properties: 1) N(0)=0, 2) Independent-increment, 3) $P\{ N(t+h)-N(t) \ge 2\}=o(h)$ and 4) $P\{  N(t+h)-N(t)=1  \} = \lambda(t)h+o(h)$.

Comment: If $\lambda(t)$ is strictly positive, you might want to consider the inverse function of $m(t)$ and whether you can use that to construct a Poisson process with constant rate $1$